# Set LifeCyleRule on Single Object AWS S3 .NET SDK

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is it possible to set LifeCycleRule to individual object in the bucket in AWS S3. I have found a way to apply it to the bucket, but I think that it is applicable for all the objects in the bucket with same Prefix and every time we set it removes the older rule

```
                 LifecycleConfiguration lifeCycleConfiguration = new LifecycleConfiguration()
                                {
                                    Rules = new List<LifecycleRule>
                                                                { new LifecycleRule() 
                                                                                      { Prefix = filePathWithFolder,
                                                                                        Expiration = new LifecycleRuleExpiration() {  Days = 1} 
                                                                                      }
                                                                }
                                };
            PutLifecycleConfigurationRequest lifeCycleConfigRequest = new PutLifecycleConfigurationRequest() { BucketName = paramList.BucketName + "//*", Configuration = lifeCycleConfiguration };
            client.PutLifecycleConfiguration(lifeCycleConfigRequest);
```

I think the above code apply the rule to the bucket and not to the file

Answer (score 0):

The rule applies to everything in the bucket, but *if your prefix is specific enough you can target a single file.*

Thru the console you can have up to 1000 rules for a single bucket, but if you are using the API. Using the API I don't believe there is such a limitation, so as long as you are willing/able to setup a rule per object, with the prefix targeting that single object, you should be OK.